# How to write same client text when using different implementation?

Tags: c, makefile, polymorphism, overloading, embedded-linux

I'm working on projects where I write code on both the client and supplier side.

Suppose in project_A I choose chip_A and in project_B I choose chip_B. Both chip_A and chip_B provide similar functionality.

Next, I encapsulate chip_A and chip_B into modules, respectively.

chip_a.h

```
typedef sturct
{
    uint8_t element1;
    uint8_t element2;
    ...
    uint8_t element8;
    uint8_t element9;
}chip_a_t;


bool chip_a_get_element1(chip_a_t* me);
bool chip_a_get_element2(chip_a_t* me);
...
bool chip_a_get_element8(chip_a_t* me);
bool chip_a_get_element9(chip_a_t* me);
```

chip_b.h

```
typedef sturct
{
    uint8_t element_a;
    uint8_t element_b;
    ...
    uint8_t element_y;
    uint8_t element_z;
}chip_b_t;


bool chip_b_get_element_a(chip_b_t* me);
bool chip_b_get_element_b(chip_b_t* me);
...
bool chip_b_get_element_y(chip_b_t* me);
bool chip_b_get_element_z(chip_b_t* me);
```

Suppose the program code needs an element_123 (for chip_A is a combination of element_1 and element_8, and for chip_B is a combination of element_a, element_b, element_y and element_z), and the program text is always the same even in different projects; the difference between projects is only the choice of chip.

program.c

```
agent_t agent = {0};
if (agent_get_element_123(&agent) != true) {return;}
uint8_t data = agent.element_123 + some_data;

/*do other things...*/
```

If I code agent.c like this

```
/*agent.c*/

bool agent_get_element_123(agent_t* me)
{
    chip_a_t chip_a = {0};
    if ((chip_a_get_element1(&chip_a) != true)
     || (chip_a_get_element8(&chip_a) != true))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    me->element_123 = chip_a.element1 + chip_a.element8;
    
    return true;
}
```

I will bind agent module to chip_a module, and the agent module is only available for project_A; bind agent module to chip_b being only available for project_B.

Is there a way to write the same client text (agent.c) for different projcets?

FYI:

1. Hardware only and always supports one chip. It is impossible to have two chips on one hardware.
2. One project might include code for chip_A and chip_B at the same time, because we often copy entire folder from one project to another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *SO* many ways to handle stuff like this, a lot of it depends on what exactly you want to do and what your limitations are.

For example, is the interface between the chips identical, so that the code in agent.c is the same, just with different function names?  Then you can just write all your chips to have the same API and link in whichever one you want.

If the code is different, is it possible to introduce a higher-level interface that provides a similar API across all the chips?  Then you can have each chip provide this interface and write agent.c to that interface.

You can have an array of function pointers, and each chip fill it in with their functions, then agent.c would choose the element in that array and call the function.

You can create multiple shared libraries, one for each chip, then have agent.c use dlopen() to pick the right one and dlsym() to obtain pointers to the functions.

Do you want the choice of which chip to be used to be a *compile* time decision (use a preprocessor option to choose), a *link* time decision (link in different object files with the same API), or a *run* time decision (choose different share libraries at runtime)?

Comment: There are so many information that's unfamiliar to me in this answer. I need some time to digest. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean that I can have `agent_get_element_123_by_chipA` in `agent_chip_A.c` and `agent_get_element_123_by_chipB` in `agent_chip_B.c`, then let `agent_get_element_123` to use function pointer to choose which chip to use at run-time? Or did you mean that I can have multiple `agent.c` with different implementation and choose which `agent.c` to use at compile-time?

Comment: Do you have any reference for this kind of discussion that I can study? Thank you very much

Comment: One way is to have the same function `agent_get_element_123` defined in both `agent_chip_A.c` and in `agent_chip_B.c` so that both present the same API, then `agent.c` calls `agent_get_element_123()`.  Or you can have an array of function pointers `agent_api[] = { agent_get_element_123_by_chipA };` defined in `agent_chip_A.c` and the same array `agent_api[] = { agent_get_element_123_by_chipB };` defined in `agent_chip_B.c`, then in `agent.c` you invoke `agent_api[0]();`.  I don' t know of any specific references but these are very common methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [conditional-compilation](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_078.HTM) , you need to enable your configurations for *CHIP_A* or *CHIP_B* when compiling.

suppose if you want to compile for *CHIP_A*, then

```
/* can be done in many ways, used this for simplicity */
#define CHIP_A TRUE
```

```
function()
{
    /* common code */

    #ifdef CHIP_A
    /* CHIP_A related code */
    #endif /* CHIP_A */
    
    #ifdef CHIP_B
    /* CHIP_B related code */
    #endif /* CHIP_B */

    /* common code */
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to this approach? The disadvantage of this approach is that the function size increases proportionately to the number of chips,  leading to maintenance issues.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the common approach, other option may be to use different source files for different chips and can be enabled using make options etc..

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too. Waiting for someone to provide a general guideline or references